# Home key but want to back to column header only

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Currently when I click Ctrl Home, it will go to top left of the sheet.

I would like to find out how to go to top of the column only, any shortcut key?

Example, from F181 go back to F1.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ctrl+G" should be what you want. This opens the goto dialog, where you can enter where you want to go.

"Ctrl + Up arrow" goes to the end of the active selection, which is pretty much the best you can do as far as I know, with only the Keyboard. You could however also enter the field you want to go to in the upper left corner.

[This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-shortcut-and-function-keys-HP010073848.aspx) has saved me often.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> works for me to select ColumnF (with <kbd>Up</kbd> pressed repeatedly if to 'span' blank cells) then click on `F1` to select the header. However such hot keys may be machine/configuration dependent. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (repeatedly if necessary) and you should not need to select `F1` separately.

Comment: If you have a bunch of filled rows and a large file, ctrl+up is quite a pain. I guess I'd prefer using goto after hammering up 10 times ;)